# Deployment Controller not selecting pods with same label

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks, kubernetes-deployment

I have created a pod using below yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: pod2
    labels:
       app: dc1
spec:
    containers:
      - name: cont1
        image: nginx
```

Now, I am creating a `deployment controller` with the selector value as `app=dc1` using the below command:

`kubectl create deploy dc1 --image=nginx`

Note: When we create a deployment with the name "dc1", it automatically creates selector `app=dc1` for the deployment controller.

I notice that the deployment controller `creates a new pod` instead of selecting the already existing pod.

```
NAME                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   LABELS
dc1-969ff47-ljbxk   1/1     Running   0          32m   app=dc1,pod-template-hash=969ff47
pod1                1/1     Running   0          33m   app=dc1
```

**Question:** 
Why `dc1` is not selecting the existing `pod1` which has the same label `app=dc1?`

Comment: It looks like you created a deployment with the name "dc1" but did not configure any selectors.

Comment: @jordanm When we create a deployment with the name "dc1", it automatically creates selector `app=dc1` for the deployment controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your replica set after deploying the deployment. You will notice a new label by the name ***pod-template-hash***

```
kubectl get replicasets  dc1-xxxxx  -o yaml
```

It is generated by hashing the PodTemplate

```
labels:
    app: dc1
    pod-template-hash: xxxxxxxx
```

If you define both labels on your pod, your pod then will be managed by Deployments.

But this is not recommended by the [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#selector)

> Note: You should not create other Pods whose labels match this selector, either directly, by creating another Deployment, or by creating another controller such as a ReplicaSet or a ReplicationController. If you do so, the first Deployment thinks that it created these other Pods. Kubernetes does not stop you from doing this.

Answer (score 1):

`Why dc1 is not selecting the existing pod1 which has the same label app=dc1?`

Because pod1 was not originated by a deployment which spawn a replicaset that would add `pod-template-hash` to the pod labels (which your standalone pod will not have). In your case of replicaset, you didn't have `pod-template-hash` as part of its `selector.matchLabels`. If you do add one, the replicaset will not select your standalone pod.

Comment: can you please explain more? In case of Replica Set, the same pod is getting selected by the replica set. Then, why it is not getting selected in case of deployment controller?

Comment: Checkout the updated answer.